# how to reference a .net coded library in a MFC dialog-based project

Tags: .net, c++

I want to use [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com) which is in a .NET code library. Anyone knows how to import/reference the dll file into my vc++ MFC project?

I tried right clicking on my project, choose "References...", then I click the "Add new Reference" button, and I get an empty dialog box with a single tab "Projects" which contains an empty list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call .Net code directly from unmanaged native code. You have several options if you want to do this indirectly though:

1. Convert your MFC project to be mixed-mode
2. Add an intermediate façade assembly
3. Expose htmlagilitypack via COM (if you have access) and call it via COM interop

You need to provide more context if you want a recommendation on which approach might suit your circumstances best

Comment: it seems that the 1st one is relatively easy?

Comment: yea, then tell me how to do it

Comment: i didnt find any answer there, i didnt find a step through or something similar.

Comment: i also tried turn on CLR support, and i am able to add reference to thmlagilitypack.dll, but not sure whether it will affect my previous coding in the same project? look below, this is what happened after i turn on CLR support

Comment: i got an error when i tried to build my app: 1>c:\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\xmldomfromvc\stdafx.h(50): fatal error C1083: Cannot open type library file: 'd:\htmlagilitypack.1.4.0\htmlagilitypack.dll': Error loading type library/DLL.

Comment: this is my import statement: #import "D:\HtmlAgilityPack.1.4.0\HtmlAgilityPack.dll"